# Edit file name method - run time complexity

Tags: java, performance

I wrote a function in Java that edit file name, and replace each space char into dash char.
Currently I iterate all the files in a specific directory, iterate in each file name, creating a new file name, and replace the file in the directory.

> I guess that the current complexity is \$O(N*M)\$ with
>
> - \$N\$ being the number of files in directory and
> - \$M\$ being the number of chars in each file.

Can the run-time-complexity be improved?

```
public static void editSpace(String source, String target) {

    // Source directory where all the files are there
    File dir = new File(source);
    File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();

    // Iterate in each file in the directory
    for (File file : directoryListing) {

        String childName = file.getName();
        String childNameNew = "";

        // Iterate in each file name and change every space char to dash char
        for (int i = 0; i < childName.length(); i++) {

            if (childName.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                childNameNew += "-";
            } else {
                childNameNew += childName.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        // Update the new directory of the child
        String childDir = target + "\\" + childNameNew;

        // Renaming the file and moving it to a new location
        if (!(childNameNew.equals(""))
                && (file.renameTo(new File(childDir)))) {

            // If file copied successfully then delete the original file .
            file.delete();

            // Print message
            System.out.println(childName + " File moved successfully to "
                    + childDir);
        }

        // Moving failed
        else {
            // Print message
            System.out.println(childName + " Failed to move the file to "
                    + childDir);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello and Welcome to Code Review. The runtime complexity in terms of reading characters (n files * m characters) for substitution cannot be improved, you can use the [String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) method:

```
String childName = file.getName();
String childNameNew = "";
for (int i = 0; i < childName.length(); i++) {
    if (childName.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        childNameNew += "-";
    } else {
        childNameNew += childName.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

You can substitute your block with one line:

```
String childNameNew = childName.replace(' ', '-');
```

From Java 7 it is discouraged using [File renameTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) method, you can use from class `Files` the [move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html) method and you can write the mv file part of your code in this way:

```
// Calculate oldPath and newPath for your file with Paths.get method
try {
    Files.move(oldPath, newPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);  
    System.out.println(oldPath + " File moved successfully to " + newPath);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(oldPath + " Failed moved the file to " + newPath);   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As dariosicily said, the complexity can not be improved but there are some *really dirty tricks* you can do to improve performance by minimizing the number of objects being created... Keep in mind that this optimization is a bit useless if you only have a few thousand files with short names or if the number of files needing renaming is large compared to the total number of files.

Instead of listing all files and creating a File object to represent them and then going through the file names, you can create a `FileNameFilter` that does the renaming before creating any unnecessary objects.

```
class RenamingFileNameFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    // Reuse the StringBuilder for each file.
    final StringBuilder newName = new StringBuilder(64);

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        newName.setLength(0);

        // Boolean flag that keeps track if file name changed.
        // Do the replacing manually to avoid a second iteration over
        // the file name to see if renaming is actually needed.
        boolean renameNeeded = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            final char ch = name.charAt(i);
            if (ch == ' ') {
                renameNeeded = true;
                ch = '-';
            }
            newName.append(ch);
        }

        // Only create File objects if the file needs renaming.
        if (renameNeeded) {
            File oldFile = new File(dir, name);
            File newFile = new File(dir, newName.toString());
            oldFile.renameTo(newFile);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Pass the filter to `File.list(FileNameFilter)` and the files are renamed. However, **this abuses the FileNameFilter contract by introducing a major side effect to a component that is supposed to be "read only"**, so it will confuse people who maintain the code, unless you document and name it really carefully.

Also, add error checking. :)